# How to explore CAS(es) after analysis by SimplePipeline.runPipeline using CollectionReader?

Tags: uima, ctakes, uimafit

Good day!

I am a bit stumbled by [SimplePipeline.runPipeline api](http://uima.apache.org/d/uimafit-2.0.0/api/org/apache/uima/fit/pipeline/SimplePipeline.html) with respect to using CollectionReader(s) and CollectionReaderDescription(s).
Api description says: `Run the CollectionReader and AnalysisEngines as a pipeline. After processing all CASes provided by the reader, the method calls collectionProcessComplete() on the engines and destroy() on all engines.`

It's all good except one thing, once processed, how do I access results in processed CAS(es) once analysis is finished? I don't seem to find any apis/iterators to do this.

Or more general question: If someone has an example of using CollectionReader(s) to perform such analysis or outline general approach and can share it, it is highly appreciated as there seem to be a lack of such examples in the uimafit docs.

Thanks!

Comment: did you check this section of the uimafit doc ? https://uima.apache.org/d/uimafit-current/tools.uimafit.book.html#ugr.tools.uimafit.pipelines.

Comment: @YuGagarin Could you please let us know what exactly is your use case with respective to cTAKES?

Comment: @Gandhi I have 10 million documents average size 4KB and need to extract ICD9/10 codes from them and the requirement is that everything is complete under 24 hours. So far I don't think cTakes performance is there to handle that

Comment: @YuGagarin 4KB u mean? You can always run parallel requests via REST calls that should do the job. Let me know if you need further assistance so that we can connect directly

Comment: @Gandhi Parallel requests to where? To a cluster or a single box? How many cTakes process instances do you suggest to start handling the processing? What is a throughput? Currently single analysis for me takes ~2-4 seconds per document.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the throughput that one could expect with cTAKES, but a common mistake people make is calling runPipeline with reader/engine-descriptions for each document they want to process. It is only efficient for batch processing - i.e. the reader is expected to iterate through al documents. If you are looking for a document-by-document scenario, other approaches to coding the pipeline are more efficient.